# Converting week index to day in Mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have weekdays store like 1,2,3 instead of Sunday, Monday, Tuesday etc..(1= Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday).

[image]

now I want to retrieve like Sunday, monday instead 1 and 2
I tried using  DATE_FORMAT(date,format).. but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `case` statement:

```
select (case day when 1 then 'Sunday'
                 when 2 then 'Monday'
                 when 3 then 'Tuesday'
                 when 4 then 'Wednesday'
                 when 5 then 'Thursday'
                 when 6 then 'Friday'
                 when 7 then 'Saturday'
        end) as DayOfWeek
```

Or, in MySQL, you can also use `ELT()`:

```
select elt(day, 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')
```

Comment: I know this. looking for some inbuilt function.

Comment: Gordon's answer is the way to go.